# WebRTC ICE candidate not generating after setRemoteDescription

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am trying to setup WebRTC ( implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006' )for video and voice call. I can see the exchange of SDP via websocket by creating offer then receive the answer from other user. However, after successfully receiving SDP answer from user, I save it via `peerConnection.setRemoteDescription().`

```
SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,sdp_ice_VALUE);
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SdpObserver() {
     @Override
     public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
        }

       @Override
       public void onSetSuccess() {
          Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: ");
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onCreateFailure: ");
       }

       @Override
       public void onSetFailure(String s) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onSetFailure: ");
       }}, sessionDescription);
```

I can see the onSetSuccess call in logcat, which means the remote description is set successfully. However, ICE candidate is not generating.

I have checked the code several times and I can't find any obvious errors. Could anyone help me to debug this issue?

Here is the complete code/fragment

```
public class Video_Voice_Call_Fragment extends Fragment {

    

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        greenCallButton = view.findViewById(R.id.call_connect);
        redCallButton = view.findViewById(R.id.call_disconnect);
        initializeWebRTC();
        startCall();
    }


    

    private void initializeWebRTC() {
        rootEglBase = EglBase.create();

        // Initialize PeerConnectionFactory
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(requireContext())
                .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                .createInitializationOptions());

        DefaultVideoEncoderFactory videoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),true,true);
        DefaultVideoDecoderFactory videoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
        PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(videoDecoderFactory)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(videoEncoderFactory)
                .setOptions(options)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory();

    }




    private void startCall() {
        // Create an offer and set local description
        peerConnection = generateICE();
        peerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: " + sessionDescription.description);
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                Websocket.connectWebSocket(new WebSocketCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuccess() {
                        //Websocket Connected
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuccess: Websocket Connected");
                        String message = generateJSON(sessionDescription.description,true,"offer");
                        Websocket.sendMessage(message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailure(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailure: Message = "+message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionClosed(String reason) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionClosed: Reason = "+reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionsMessage(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Message = "+message);
                        // Here User will receive the message from the websocket
                        try{
                            JSONObject socketMessage = new JSONObject(message);
                            String type = socketMessage.getString("type");
                            String sdp_ice_VALUE = socketMessage.getString("SDP_ICE_info");
                            if (type.equals("SDP")){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Type SDP");
                                SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,sdp_ice_VALUE);
                                peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SdpObserver() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSetSuccess() {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: ");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateFailure: ");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSetFailure(String s) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onSetFailure: ");
                                    }
                                }, sessionDescription);
                               
                            }else {
                                // Received ICE from server as answer, This is the last step in exchanging info
                                WebRTCUtils.addIceCandidate(peerConnection,sdp_ice_VALUE);
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Error "+e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Send the offer to the remote peer
                // Example code for sending the offer
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCreateFailure: " + s);
            }
        }, new MediaConstraints());
    }

    private PeerConnection generateICE (){
        Log.d(TAG, "generateICE: ");
        ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> STUNList= Arrays.asList(
                "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun.vodafone.ro:3478",
                "stun:stun.samsungsmartcam.com:3478",
                "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com:3478"

        );
        for(String i:STUNList){
            PeerConnection.IceServer.Builder iceServerBuilder = PeerConnection.IceServer.builder(i);
            iceServerBuilder.setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK); //this does the magic.
            PeerConnection.IceServer iceServer =  iceServerBuilder.createIceServer();
            iceServers.add(iceServer);
        }
        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);

        PeerConnection.Observer observer = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: "+signalingState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: "+iceConnectionState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: Boolean = "+b);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: "+iceGatheringState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: "+iceCandidate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: "+iceCandidates);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: "+mediaStream);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: "+mediaStream);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: "+dataChannel);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddTrack: "+rtpReceiver+"--- "+mediaStreams);
            }
        };
        Log.d(TAG, "generateICE: ");
        return peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig,observer);
        
        
    }


}
```

**Update:-** With the suggestions from @PhilippHancke. I edit my code:-

```
private void setupLocalTracks() {
        // Create video capturer
        videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();

        // Create video source
        videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false);
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("local_video", videoSource);
        // Create audio source and track
        AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
        localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("local_audio", audioSource);

        // Create local media stream
        localMediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("local_stream");
        localMediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
        localMediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
        peerConnection.addStream(localMediaStream);

    }
```

Now i can see much more details in log which has SDP offer/answer and ice too.I first call  `peerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver()`which generate SessionDescription for User ID 4.

```
Message Received From User ID == 4 Message = v=0
o=- 5794866635417549132 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS local_stream
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:EXXZ
a=ice-pwd:NuOsEt2YVDiZkxFomvHPhUW+
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F2:1E:77:5D:21:00:15:65:00:CA:24:BE:65:66:95:09:B4:10:4C:80:C0:16:90:4A:22:E7:ED:BA:D4:A8:F5:56
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:473446091 cname:WQlLPNcKBxol0kL2
a=ssrc:473446091 msid:local_stream local_audio
a=ssrc:473446091 mslabel:local_stream
a=ssrc:473446091 label:local_audio
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 123 125
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:EXXZ
a=ice-pwd:NuOsEt2YVDiZkxFomvHPhUW+
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F2:1E:77:5D:21:00:15:65:00:CA:24:BE:65:66:95:09:B4:10:4C:80:C0:16:90:4A:22:E7:ED:BA:D4:A8:F5:56
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:127 red/90000
a=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:123 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 1370797121 3619002051
a=ssrc:1370797121 cname:WQlLPNcKBxol0kL2
a=ssrc:1370797121 msid:local_stream local_video
a=ssrc:1370797121 mslabel:local_stream
a=ssrc:1370797121 label:local_video
a=ssrc:3619002051 cname:WQlLPNcKBxol0kL2
a=ssrc:3619002051 msid:local_stream local_video
a=ssrc:3619002051 mslabel:local_stream
a=ssrc:3619002051 label:local_video

Message Received From User ID == 206 Message = v=0
o=- 3655990368999828607 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS remote_stream
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:0O57
a=ice-pwd:FSyUVENoJglSvKVpeih/bzXA
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B8:43:6B:EE:38:08:19:85:DA:97:AA:45:2D:46:17:90:9E:8B:D2:D8:D7:9D:04:97:22:DE:C9:CB:FC:A1:DB:5B
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:624557633 cname:PYJF7YMAd+hgS7Zk
a=ssrc:624557633 msid:remote_stream remote_audio
a=ssrc:624557633 mslabel:remote_stream
a=ssrc:624557633 label:remote_audio
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 123 125
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:0O57
a=ice-pwd:FSyUVENoJglSvKVpeih/bzXA
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B8:43:6B:EE:38:08:19:85:DA:97:AA:45:2D:46:17:90:9E:8B:D2:D8:D7:9D:04:97:22:DE:C9:CB:FC:A1:DB:5B
a=setup:active
a=mid:video
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:127 red/90000
a=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:123 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 2171330257 4072720398
a=ssrc:2171330257 cname:PYJF7YMAd+hgS7Zk
a=ssrc:2171330257 msid:remote_stream remote_video
a=ssrc:2171330257 mslabel:remote_stream
a=ssrc:2171330257 label:remote_video
a=ssrc:4072720398 cname:PYJF7YMAd+hgS7Zk
a=ssrc:4072720398 msid:remote_stream remote_video
a=ssrc:4072720398 mslabel:remote_stream
a=ssrc:4072720398 label:remote_video
```

In the SDP above i can ICE candidates too which creates confusion for me because when other receive this SDP then how user would save it, as SDP (setRemoteDescription) or treat it as ICE candidates beucase it contains both.

Also i can see in log that `onIceCandidate` calls multiples times with these kinds of values

```
audio:0:candidate:1587269880 1 udp 2122262783 2406:b400:52:820d:70e0:90ff:fe12:3352 35364 typ host generation 0 ufrag B/Tc network-id 4 network-cost 10::UNKNOWN

audio:0:candidate:393917512 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.0.123 42552 typ host generation 0 ufrag B/Tc network-id 3 network-cost 10::UNKNOWN

audio:0:candidate:559267639 1 udp 2122136831 ::1 50036 typ host generation 0 ufrag B/Tc network-id 2::UNKNOWN
```

Do i need to send these information to other user as ICE (it calls around 10 times approx) every time it calls `onIceCandidate`?

After these exchange which method should i call to initiate the call?

Comment: Check this for more information about your issue:- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-sdp-14

Answer (score 1):

ICE candidates are only generated after you call setLocalDescription, see https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#set-the-session-description step 4 substep 2.

(please also note that org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006 is an outdated version that has known security vulnerabilities)

Comment: setlocatDescription at SDP? . I am doing this but still i dont see any log in console for ICE

Comment: The other option is that you are not adding any tracks, the generated SDP does not have any m= lines and these are required for gathering candidates.

Comment: You mean add strem?